# bootstrap support for couple of breakpoints

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I have a requirement to provide only 2 breakpoints for one of the application. This 2 breakpoints are <=768 is mobile & 1280 >= desktop. ( No Tablet breakpoint)

How can I modify `$grid-breakpoints` to support this structure ?

I believe is it like :

`$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1280px
);`

where  I will only cater for `md`,`xl` and ignore `sm` , `md` & `lg` ?

Kindly provide suggestions ?

Comment: you want overwrite your bootstrap css with these breakpoints?

Comment: why u need to override bootstrap breakpoint?? use media queries instead.

Comment: I will use Grid classes and components as well.

Comment: Customization feature is not yet available in Bootstrap 4. You have update manually in your bootstrap library.

Comment: It's not ideal, but for the SASS variables above, make XS, SM, MD all the same value, and the same for LG and XL. That should effectively so the same thing, even if it is a little _ugh_.

Comment: @Lewis: Yeah. I was thinking towards the same. but even with the `grid` variable which I have pasted in question, if I provide column classes only for "md" & "xl",  will that be enough as well ?

Comment: @Robin Probably not. Some classes like `.container` respond to breakpoints under the hood without any additional user intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your question is really about *3* breakpoints. The description of `<=768 is mobile & 1280 >= desktop` is missing the range *between* 768 and 1280.

Assuming you meant these 3 breakpoints:

- `<=768` (implied or 'xs')
- `>768 & <1280` (md)
- `>=1280` (xl)

The SASS customizations are easy:

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  md: 768px,
  xl: 1280px
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

https://codeply.com/go/GZJHsDyeH2

Comment: What happens to classes that rely on the missing breakpoints, such as `.container`? Will they just adapt?

Comment: You could use `$container-max-widths` (as shown in the Codeply) to control which media queries are created for container width.

Comment: @Zim : Thanks for your suggestion. 

So the container width is what the only caveat or do I need to handle anything apart from this?

Comment: @Zim: did you get a chance to see my earlier query ?

Comment: Even though , the interim bootstrap breakpoint `sm` is getting applied.

Comment: @Zim:  The bootstrap's 576px contains 540 container width. That is getting applied even though `max-width` is not specified. I want container width=100% until 767px.

Comment: Ok I have overwritten it by putting 100% `
$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 100%,
  md: 750px,
  xl: 1200px
);`

Comment: @Robin - I am trying to achieve a similar result.  Did you run into problems with using a percentage for the small breakpoint $container-max-width?  I thought the values had to be in pixels?  (I am trying to force the container max-width to be 100% for mobile and tablet)..